# Trying to implement a cleanup in a useEffect to prevent no-op memory leak error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, race-condition, no-op

I am trying to update a piece of UI based on a conditional. The conditional is set by a database call in a separate component. It sometimes works, but often doesn't. When it doesn't work, it gets this error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I have followed other advice and tried to do a cleanup in a useEffect:

```
const [isPatched, setIsPatched] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    x.Log ? setPatched(true) : setPatched(false);
    return () => {
      setIsPatched(false);
    };
  }, []);

  const setPatched = (patched: boolean) => {
    setIsPatched(patched);
  };
```

Other component db call:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled === true) {
      const handle = setTimeout(() => setDisabled(false), 7000);
      return () => clearTimeout(handle);
    }
  }, [disabled]);

  function handleClick() {
   [...]
    const updatePatchedX = async (id: string) => {
      //check if patched x already in db
      const content = await services.xData.getxContent(id);
      const xyToUpdated = content?.p[0] as T;

      if (!xToUpdated.log) {
        // add log property to indicate it is patched and put in DB
        xToUpdated.log = [
          { cId: cId ?? "", uId: uId, appliedAt: Date.now() },
        ];

        if (content) {
          await services.xData
            .updateOTxBook(id, content, uId)
            .then(() => {
              console.log("done");
              setPatched(true);
              setDisabled(true);
            });
        }
      }
    };

    updatePatchedX(notebookID);
  }
```

The UI is only fixed on refresh - not immediately, as the useEffect is supposed to achieve? Not sure where to go from here. Could be a race condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this in the past and here's what I learned from it

1. This is normally caused by this sequence of events:

   user clicks button => triggers API call => UI changes and the button gets unmounted => API call finishes and tries to update the state of a component that has been unmounted
2. If the action could be canceled then the default recommendation of "To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function." makes sense; but in this case the API call cannot be cancelled.
3. The only solution I've found to this is using a ref to track whether the component has been unmounted by the time the API call completes

Below a snippet with just the relevant changes for simplicity

```js
const mainRef = useRef(null);

function handleClick() {
   [...]
    const updatePatchedX = async (id: string) => {
      ...
          await services.xData
            .updateOTxBook(id, content, uId)
            .then(() => {
              if (mainRef.current) {
                console.log("done");
                setPatched(true);
                setDisabled(true);
              }
            });
      ...
    };

    updatePatchedX(notebookID);
  }

return (
  <div ref={mainRef}>.... <button onClick={handleClick}>...</button></div>
);
```

The above works because when the component gets unmounted the `myRef` references get emptied but you can still check its value when the API call eventually fulfills and before you use some `setState` function

Comment: Nice dude, this fixed the no-op error thank you!!